# PHP only store 1048576 characters in array

Tags: php, mysql, character, limit

I'm working on a project that parses huge text files and store some of the information in MySQL DB. I noticed one of the field was missing info when it was displayed, however, when checking the DB (from phpmyadmin), it shows the data is complete, so the problem must be with  the php, before the length of the array field is 1048576, whereas there are 1235597 characters in DB.

My php info shows memory_limit is 2048M, 
Mysql config shows:
    [mysqld]
    key_buffer              = 32M
    max_allowed_packet      = 32M

I don't know what else could have caused the problem... someone please help!!!

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: 1048576 would seem to be one megabyte - I'd assume you were running into an internal storage limit in PHP.

Comment: @andrewsi: No way there would be such a small internal limit to anything.

Comment: Are you reading a blob field from database?

Comment: I think we need a little more info. If you could extract the code that's giving you trouble from the project we could probably come up with something.

Comment: @svrcoder: No, I'm reading a longtext field.

Comment: @andrewsi: That is what I'm guessing too, but the question is what...

Comment: @ChrisHanson: Chris, my code is as simple as a query and print the length of the string. However, I can tell you that I'm using Laravel as the framework, so the query looks like:

    $titles = DB::query("SELECT title FROM ".$tablePrefix."config");

but it should not be a problem, because it is working every where else. I don't understand why I could write those info into the DB no problem, but not able to get them in one piece.

Comment: @SeanYang, please provide code for investigation which part can bring error.

Answer (score 2):

PDO's default buffer size is 1 MB (1048576), try bumping it up to 2 MB (2097152)

If you are using PDO directly, pass this as the 4th argument

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    $dsn,
    $username,
    $password,
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 2097152)
);
```

If you are using Laravel, this can be done via the config/database.php file by adding an array of options to your connection

```
// ...
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        // ...
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'options'   => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 2097152
        ),
    ),
// ...
```