# How to retrieve large data from mysql to php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I retrieve large data from mysql to php? I've tried, but I'm getting a **1048576** characters string and my row is bigger than that.

Comment: what's your mysql column data type?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223847/php-only-store-1048576-characters-in-array

Comment: my column type is medium text

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to Pablo Jiménez, that was quick.

Pdo's buffer was indeed too small, by doing so i was able to retrieve my data.

```
$pdo = new PDO(
$dsn,
$username,
$password,
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 2097152)
```

);