# Why does array_pad prevent to add at more than 1048576 elements at a time?

Tags: php, arrays

[The `array_pad` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) say that

> It is possible to add at most 1048576 elements at a time.

I tried to find any information where the limit comes from and could not find any. The only somehow related question are about PDO: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223847/php-only-store-1048576-characters-in-array), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499063/how-to-retrieve-large-data-from-mysql-to-php) and the solution is to enlarge the size of the buffer. But there is no PDO in `array_pad`.

It is absolutely possible to create an array that contains more elements:

```
$array = range(1, 1048576 + 10);
echo count($array); // prints 1048586
```

And indeed, there is a hardcoded check not to exceed this value in [the `array_pad` sources](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/121331b2ce6254d8b640bcc14ebc57d4ef558060/ext/standard/array.c#L4306).

But... why?

Comment: It is hardcoded in the source - https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L4306. I guess it's just old guess for safe limit to prevent from memory exhaust. Probably should be adjusted for PHP7+. BTW 1048576 = 2^20.

Comment: For me `$array = range(1, 8299999);` works but `$array = range(1, 8399999);` does not work. So it seems the limit is much higher than docs say. EDIT; `$array = range(1, 8388608);`is the hard limit for me. one more and it fails.

Comment: One may use `generators` for adding more than 1048576 items - http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php. Generators are very fast, memory effective and very flexible, though more complex than a single function call :-)

Comment: 2x2 = 4x2 = 8x2 = 16x2 = 32x2 = 64x2 = 128x2 = 256x2 = 512x2 = 1024x2 = 2048x2 = 4096x2 =  8192x2 = 16384x2 = 32768x2 = 65536x2 = 131072x2 = 262144x2 = 524288x2 = 1048576

Answer (score 0):

**Why `range` produce an array of more than 1048576 elements?**

From PHP sources:

```
// ext/standard/array.c
PHP_FUNCTION(range)
{
   ...
   Z_PARAM_ZVAL(zlow)
   Z_PARAM_ZVAL(zhigh)
   Z_PARAM_OPTIONAL
   Z_PARAM_ZVAL(zstep)
   ...
   RANGE_CHECK_LONG_INIT_ARRAY(low, high);
   ...
```

`RANGE_CHECK_LONG_INIT_ARRAY` Macro checks if the size of the requested sequence doesn't exceed or equal the max size `HT_MAX_SIZE - 1`(HashTable Max Size)

```
// ext/standard/array.c
#define RANGE_CHECK_LONG_INIT_ARRAY(start, end) do { \
        zend_ulong __calc_size = (start - end) / lstep; \
        if (__calc_size >= HT_MAX_SIZE - 1) { \
            php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "The supplied range exceeds the maximum array size: start=" ZEND_LONG_FMT " end=" ZEND_LONG_FMT, end, start); \
            RETURN_FALSE; \
        } \
```

HT_MAX_SIZE value:

```
// Zend/types_types.h
#if SIZEOF_SIZE_T == 4 // 32 bit
# define HT_MAX_SIZE 0x04000000 /* small enough to avoid overflow checks */
...
#elif SIZEOF_SIZE_T == 8 // 64 bit
# define HT_MAX_SIZE 0x80000000
```

So we can see that the max size of the array that will be generated by `rang()` is: 0x04000000 - 2 = 67108862 on 32 bit systems and 0x80000000 - 2 = 2147483646 on 64 bit systems.

```
php > echo count(range(0,67108863));
PHP Warning:  range(): The supplied range exceeds the maximum array size: start=0 end=67108863 in php shell code on line 1


php > echo count(range(0,67108862));
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1610612744 bytes) in php shell code on line 1
```

**Why does `array_pad` prevent to add more than 1048576 elements at a time?**

From PHP sources:

```
// ext/standard/array.c
PHP_FUNCTION(array_pad)
{
    ...
    if (pad_size_abs < 0 || pad_size_abs - input_size > Z_L(1048576)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "You may only pad up to 1048576 elements at a time");
        RETURN_FALSE;
     }
```

The value 1048576 is hard encoded.